# Lists with sections in android?

Tags: android, listview

Does Android-Jely-Bean's ListView support sections or do they have to be implemented manually?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement this manually whith a ListFragment, ListActivity or a normal Activity with a Listview. Take a look at [Jeff Sharkey](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/). It should be solve your problem with the sections...you only have to change the row layout.

Comment: As I guessed - there is such a thing like "Section Divider" in the   Android 4.x ListViews. This functionality doesn't have to be implemented manually anymore. See http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html

Comment: The implementation of sucha List is described here: https://github.com/steprobe/ListDemo